# prototype javascript

Tags: javascript

Cannot understand:

```
function Rabbit() { }
Rabbit.prototype = { eats: true };
var rabbit = new Rabbit();
Rabbit.prototype = {};
alert(rabbit.eats); //true
```

And

```
function Rabbit() { }
Rabbit.prototype = { eats: true };
var rabbit = new Rabbit();
Rabbit.prototype.eats = false;
alert(rabbit.eats); // false
```

Why? 
Thanks everyone for help, I get it after "In your first example, you change Rabbit.prototype to point to an entirely new, different, object. So now Rabbit.prototype and rabbit.[[Proto]] no longer point to the same object" (c) T.J. Crowder

Comment: So ? what were you expecting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the prototype behind the `rabbit` instance is assigned (from `Rabbit.prototype`) when it's created via `new Rabbit`, and in the first example you *replace* `Rabbit.prototype` with an entirely new object, which has no effect on the `rabbit` instance. In the second example, you just *modify* the existing object, which both `Rabbit.prototype` and the prototype behind `rabbit` are pointing to, so since they're pointing to the same object, you see the change regardless of which reference you follow.

Let's walk through `var rabbit = new Rabbit();` (leaving out some irrelevant details):

1. A new, blank object gets created.
2. Its underlying prototype, usually called `[[Proto]]`, is set to `Rabbit.prototype`. (I say "usually called" because that's what the specification calls it. You can't access it by that name directly. You can find out what it is for a given object, though, in an ES5-enabled environment via [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2). Some JavaScript engines also make it available via a non-standard property actually called [in code] `__proto__`.)
3. That new object is returned and assigned to `rabbit`.

Now, we have two objects pointing to the prototype object: `Rabbit.prototype`, and `rabbit.[[Proto]]`.

In your first example, you change `Rabbit.prototype` to point to an entirely new, different, object. So now `Rabbit.prototype` and `rabbit.[[Proto]]` no longer point to the same object.

In your second example, you just change the value of that shared object's `eats` property, so naturally that change is visible regardless of which reference to the object you follow.

It's basically the same as this:

```
var a = {eats: true};
var b = a;
a = {eats: false};
console.log(a.eats); // false
console.log(b.eats); // true
```

and

```
var a = {eats: true};
var b = a;
a.eats = false;
console.log(a.eats); // false
console.log(b.eats); // false
```

Comment: So basically saying, although prototype is assigned to `.prototype` in object `rabbit`, the object actually gets it's properties from `[[proto]]`? What's the point of `.prototype` then?

Comment: @freakish: `Rabbit.prototype` is just a property on the `Rabbit` function object. It's not special except that that property gets *used* by the `new Rabbit` expression. There is no enduring link at all between `Rabbit.prototype` and the `[[Proto]]` property on `rabbit`. They just happen (initially) to point to the same object.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was a bit confusing for me. Now it's clear, thanks. :)

Comment: @freakish: For you and a *bunch* of other people. :-) I think it's the name of the property on the function object that does it (it's what confused me originally, some years back). If they'd called it `prototypeToAssignToNewObjects` or some such silliness, it might have been clearer. But more clunky. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Rabbit.prototype = { eats: true };
```

is equivalent to

```
Rabbit.prototype = {};
Rabbit.prototype.eats = true;
```

And

```
Rabbit.prototype.eats = false;
```

just makes `Rabbit.prototype.eats` `false` (thus voiding the precedent assignation).

And as the js engine, when looking for a property, looks for the one of its prototype (and so on) if it doesn't find it locally, it makes `Rabbit.eats` evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the constructed object remains linked to the original prototype object, which of course still has the "eats" property.

In the second case, you're not introducing a new prototype, so changing the value of its "eats" property is visible via the instance.